# GPG: Generating key fails with cannot get input error

Tags: github, gnupg

I was trying to generate new GPG key on my Ubuntu 16.10 for GitHub. However, it ended with an error message `gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input`. I tried `gpg2` as well with no difference.

Including terminal output:

```
greeny@greenyNB:~$ gpg2 --gen-key
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11; Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input


greeny@greenyNB:~$ gpg --gen-key
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20; Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
```

How can I fix this to be able to generate GPG key?

Comment: Please post your `gpg.conf` file, ie. is there anything like `no-tty` contained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jens Erat for his comment, solution: remove `no-tty` line from `gpg.conf`.